# Wilcoxon-signed rank test gives non-significant difference on obviously different samples?

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have two samples:

```
        Sample_1   Sample_2
    1    30.32      5.93    
    2    25.65      15.21   
    3    38.7       28.33   
    4    15.47      21.33   
    5    18.91      19.46   
    6    45.26      23.93   
    7    19.03      10.18   
    8    13.14      9.89
```

The values are the result of some analysis run over different proteins.

This is raw, not normally distributed data, so I have decided to run Wilcoxon-signed ranked test. I am trying to compare two samples (`sample_1 to sample_2`) over 8 proteins (8 vs 8). So looking by eye, it is clear that `sample_1` shows better performance (higher number), but when I run the test, it tells me that there is no statistical difference.

Am I doing something wrong or this can be expected? Should I normalize my data?

Comment: Are these data paired? By that I mean: Were both methods tested on the same 8 samples?

Comment: @COOLSerdash Sorry I have just edited it to make it more understandable. The method I used to get these numbers is the same, but the difference is in the sample_1 and sample_2. So yes, it is a pair data. I have tested same method over all 8 proteins. For each protein there are two types of samples (1 and 2), so for each protein I use the same method and I get two numbers, one for sample_1 and another for sample_2. So now I want to compare sample_1 to sample_2 over 8 proteins. Hope it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Paired data.** I will put our data into R and take a look. (You may want to proofread my data entry.)

```
x1 = c(30.32,25.65,38.7, 15.47,18.91,45.26,19.03,13.14)
x2 = c( 5.93,15.21,28.33,21.33,19.45,23.96,10.18, 9.89)
d = x1-x2
summary(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -5.860   2.303   9.610   9.025  13.155  24.390 
stripchart(d)
 abline(v = 0, col="green")
```

[image]

**Wilcoxon signed rank test of differences.**

*Two-sided test:* A Wilcoxon signed rank test on the pairs to see if differences
(Meth 1 - Meth 2) are significantly *different* from 0, is not
quite significant at the 5% level (P-value just above 0.05).
Formally, we are testing $H_0: \delta = 0$ against
$H_a: \delta \ne 0,$ where $\delta$ is the population difference in pairs.

```
wilcox.test(d)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  d
V = 32, p-value = 0.05469
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```

*One-sided test:* If you suspected from the start that Method 1 gives higher scores,
you would do a one-sided test $H_0: \delta = 0$ against
$H_a: \delta > 0.$ Then the P-value $0.02734 < .0.5$ is half as large
as for the two-sided test above. So you can say that the
scores for Method 1 are significantly *greater* than those for Method 2.

```
wilcox.test(d, alt="greater")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  d
V = 32, p-value = 0.02734
alternative hypothesis: true location is greater than 0
```

**Possible paired t tests.** Furthermore, although it is difficult to say for sure with only eight differences, your differences are not obviously different
from a sample from a normal population.

*Shapiro-Wilk test of normality:* A Shapiro-Wilk test of
normality finds that the differences are consistent with a normal sample. There is no obvious skewness in the stripchart of the
differences and there are no outliers.

```
shapiro.test(d)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  d
W = 0.95688, p-value = 0.7799
```

*Two-sided and one-sided paired t tests:* In these circumstances
it seems OK to do paired t tests. A two-sided test is barely
significant at the 5% level; a one-sided test shows a P-value $0.021 < 0.05.$

```
t.test(d)

        One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = 2.4877, df = 7, p-value = 0.04173
alternative hypothesis: 
  true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.4466653 17.6033347
sample estimates: 
mean of x 
    9.025 

t.test(d, alt="greater")$p.val
[1] 0.02086697
```

*Note:* You should be a little careful claiming that the 
Method 1 scores are "obviously" larger than Method 2 for the same protein. While some paired Wilcoxon and t tests do suggest a difference, the evidence is not overwhelmingly strong with P-values larger than 0.01.

Also, two out of eight of your differences are *negative.*
If negative and positive differences were equally likely, it would not be surprising to see as many as two negative values. If $S = \mathsf{Binom}(n=8, p=12), then $P(S \le 2) = 0.1445.$

```
pbinom(2, 8, 1/2)
[1] 0.1445313
```

Comment: just to ask you few questions to make sure I understood everything. Two way/sided test (Wilcoxon or t-test) assumes that non of the methods has a higher score? On the other hand one sided (Wilcoxon or t-test) assumes that one of the methods has a higher score?  So I guess its always good to use two-sided tests? Since I have more samples to test, do you think it makes sense to first do Sharipo-Wilk test in order to test if the differences in my samples are consistent with a normal sample? If they are consistent, I go for two-sided t-test, if not consistent I go for two-sided Wilcoxon?

Comment: **1 vs 2-sided:** If you have no advance clue that Meth 1 > Meth 2 in advance of taking data, then 2-sided. You shouldn't make this decision after looking at data. (Otherwise all tests would be one-sided.) **Robustness of t tests.** With a moderate amt of data (maybe $n>15),$ not strongly skewed and with no far outliers, many statisticians would feel it's OK to use a t test. I wouldn't automatically abandon t tests every time a Shapiro-Wilk test rejects normality.

Comment: I see. ALso, since I am comparing samples over different proteins (1,2,3,4,5..8) and this is raw data. I have heard some people suggesting to normalize it to make comparison more fair? Also if Sharipo-Wilk test if p-value is over 0.05, does it automatically means my data difference is consistent with normal sample?

Comment: Your (latest) first question should probably asked as a separate formal Question--with all the necessary context on display.  // Shapiro-Wilk is one of the best normality tests, but it's not perfect. For small samples often fails to reject non-normal data, For huge sample often rejects samples that are nearly but not precisely normal.(Maybe [see](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3693611/))

Comment: Your answer was very useful. I learned a lot. I will run the analysis on my other and bigger samples and maybe if I have some hesitations that I dont find the answer for, I will post it as another questions with necessary display.